# How to create SFTP user with specified directory permissions

Tags: linux, sftp, chroot

I have done the following tutorial: [How to Create SFTP User with Specified Directory Permissions in Ubuntu 20.04](https://linuxways.net/ubuntu/how-to-create-sftp-user-with-specified-directory-permissions-in-ubuntu-20-04/).

Creating new Sftp User:

```
# useradd -m -d /home/example.com sftp_user
# passwd sftp_user
```

Setup Directory Permissions:

```
# chmod 755 /home/example.com/
# chown root:root /home/example.com
```

Restrict Directory Access:

```
# vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config
subsystem sftp internal-sftp
Match User sftp_user
ChrootDirectory %h
AllowTCPForwarding no
X11Forwarding no
PasswordAuthentication yes
ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Now my problem is the user don't see his own home folder (`/home/example.com`). If I change the permissions for this folder to `sftp_user`, than I get a disconnection error if I try to login. What do I need to change?

Comment: I've done exactly what he did all the steps, but my ftp client WILL NOT CONNECT, but as soon as I remove all the changes and put sshd_config file the way it was before, my ftp client connects. Then, open ups to the user's HOME folder exposing the whole filesystem. It doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

> the user doesn't see his own home folder (`/home/example.com`)

Yes and no. The directive `ChrootDirectory %h` makes the real `/home/example.com` appear as `/` to the user. The user sees this `/`, so he kinda sees what the OS considers his home directory; he doesn't see it as `/home/example.com` though. The user cannot write to the directory because of the ownership and permissions you set up. These are nevertheless right:

> `ChrootDirectory`
>
> Specifies the pathname of a directory to `chroot(2)` to after authentication. At session startup `sshd(8)` checks that all components of the pathname are root-owned directories which are not writable by any other user or group.

<sup>(source: [`man 5 sshd_config`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#ChrootDirectory))</sup>

But then:

> After the chroot, `sshd(8)` changes the working directory to the user's home directory.

<sup>(ibid.)</sup>

In your case the server tries to change the working directory to `/home/example.com` *after* the chroot, i.e. when `/` already corresponds to the real `/home/example.com`. Outside of the chroot this would be `/home/example.com/home/example.com`.

The easiest fix now is to create this exact directory with sane permissions. Do the following on the server:

```
# as root
mkdir -p /home/example.com/home/example.com
chown sftp_user: /home/example.com/home/example.com
```

From now on the user will see `/home/example.com` and be able to use it, but on the server this will be `/home/example.com/home/example.com`.

This may seem over-complicated, but in general it makes sense. In general you don't have to use sole `%h` as `ChrootDirectory`. If you don't restrict the user to sftp, you need to put few things (a shell, basic `/dev` nodes) in what the user sees as their `/`; and/or you may want few users to share a common chroot. In this scenario `ChrootDirectory /chroot_jail` makes more sense than `ChrootDirectory %h`. Then you would need `/chroot_jail/home/example.com` instead of this odd-looking `/home/example.com/home/example.com`. Our solution uses `home/example.com` inside `/home/example.com/` because you used `ChrootDirectory %h`.

---

[Yo dawg](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/xzibit-yo-dawg), I herd you like `home/example.com`, so I put `home/example.com` in your `/home/example.com/` so you can access your files while you access your files.

Comment: + 1 for the yo dawg at end!