# SFTP disconnects if directory owner is not root

Tags: linux, ssh, debian, permissions, sftp

I'm on Debian 11, using openssh-server 8.4, trying to build an sftp server for HTML uploads.

The upload destination directory is "/var/www/html" and the username is "sftp-user".
Also, the server domain is assumed here to be example.com.

I changed the "Subsystem" line in the "/etc/ssh/sshd_config" file to

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
```

, and added the following line to change port 22 to sftp only.

```
Match LocalPort 22
        AllowTCPForwarding no
        X11Forwarding no
        ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

After that line, I added the following line to specify the upload destination directory:

```
Match user sftp-user
        ChrootDirectory /var/www/html
        PermitTunnel no
        AllowAgentForwarding no
        ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

I restarted sshd with systemctl here.

The owner user of the /var/www/html directory should be www-data, so I created a group called "uploders" and specified the group to have ownership of that directory using the following command. And added the user "sftp-user" to the "uploaders" group.

```
groupadd uploaders
chown -R /var/www/html www-data:uploaders
gpasswd -a sftp-user uploaders
```

Finally, execute the following command to specify the mode of "/var/www/html" so that the group can also read and write.

```
chmod -R 0775 /var/www/html
```

And try to access the server with sftp command:

```
sftp -P 22 sftp-user@example.com
```

However, the following message is output and the connection is closed.

```
Connection to example.com closed by remote host.
Connection closed.  
Connection closed
```

However, if I change the owner of "/var/www/html/" to root, I can access it without any problem.
As mentioned earlier, the directory must be owned by www-data and cannot be changed. Is there a way to enable sftp access even when the directory owner is not root?

Comment: Related: [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1731939/432690), where it quotes the manual. "At session startup `sshd(8)` checks that all components of the pathname are root-owned directories which are not writable by any other user or group."

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1369036/how-to-create-an-ftp-sftp-user-to-manage-var-www-which-is-owned-by-www-data